# How to set a specific program to open revision temp files in git extensions

Tags: git, git-extensions

I've used git extensions quite a bit but I still haven't found a way to set a default program to open the revision temporary files. Every time that I open the revision it asks me with which program I want to open it. Is there a way to set a default (e.g. notepad++ or vscode)?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if [setting a difftool](https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/release-3.4/settings.html#git-config-difftool) is enough (this was also illustrated for mergetool in [`gitextensions/gitextensions` discussion 10498](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/discussions/10498#discussioncomment-4327851).

That should open a diff or a commit in that tool.

Set also your editor:

```
git config core.editor "code --wait"
```